# How to write complex if in ksh

Tags: unix, if-statement, ksh

I dont often use ksh and I dont know how to write this :

```
if variable is empty or variable equals "no rows selected"
```

I tried :

```
if [[ -z "${NUMCARSAT}" -o "$NUMCARSAT" | tr -s " " == "no rows selected" ]]

error = syntax error '-o' unexpected


if [ -z "${NUMCARSAT}" -o "$NUMCARSAT" | tr -s " " = "no rows selected" ]

error =  test: ] missing
Usage: tr [ [-c|-C] | -[c|C]ds | -[c|C]s | -ds | -s ] [-A] String1 String2
   tr { -[c|C]d | -[c|C]s | -d | -s } [-A] String1
```

Can somebody give me the right if to write down

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a straight-forward [`ksh` if-clause](http://www.well.ox.ac.uk/~johnb/comp/unix/ksh.html#branching)

```
if  [[ -z "${NUMCARSAT}" ]] || [[ "$NUMCARSAT" != "no rows selected" ]]; then
```

To remove leading and trailing white-spaces you can use `xargs` with a here-doc(`<<<`) syntax. i.e.

```
if  [[ -z "${NUMCARSAT}" ]] || [[ $(xargs <<< "$NUMCARSAT") != "no rows selected" ]];
```

To see if this works.

```
 $ NUMCARSAT="   no rows selected    "
 $ xargs <<<"$NUMCARSAT"
 no rows selected
```

i.e. in a condition

```
  $ if [[ $(xargs <<< "$NUMCARSAT") == "no rows selected" ]]; then echo "match"; fi
  match
```

Comment: Does that mean 'not empty' ?

Comment: where is the trim ?

Comment: @mlwacosmos: What do you mean trim, the above checks if the variable `$NUMCARSAT` is empty or has the string you mentioned. To check if string is not empty do  `[[ ! -z "${NUMCARSAT}" ]] `

Comment: I would like to erase spaces before and after the string value... do a trim

Answer (score 0):

If we remove the string "no rows selected" from the start of the variable,
we only need to test for an empty string.

```
empty_or_no_rows_selected() {
  [[ -z "${1#no rows selected}" ]]
}
```

Usage:

```
if empty_or_no_rows_selected $NUMCARSAT
then
    : ....
```

Look up the working of `#`, `##`, `%`, and `%%` in Parameter Substitution.